# Entity framework error when attempting to update property on related entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

A customer can have many subscriptions, a subscription has a single customer. When retrieving the expiring subscription entities, I am also eagerly loading the associated `Customer` for each `Subscription` as follows:

```
var subscriptions = dbcontext.Subscriptions.Include(s => s.Customer).Where(s => s.Status == "Expiring");
```

Now when I attempt to update a property on the Customer of one of the returned subscriptions and call SaveChanges as follows:

```
subscription.Customer.DaysRemaining = 20;
dbcontext.SaveChanges();
```

I encounter error "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Customer' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF"

Having looked at the generated SQL, it's attempting to insert a `Customer` record. What is the reason for this? I would have  thought that EF would be aware of the `Customer` entity and would issue an SQL UPDATE statement instead.

Comment: I believe you are going to update a column that's auto incremented

Comment: @maheshsharma Thanks for your response. Yes EF is including the auto-incremented field in the INSERT statement. My question is why is it performing an INSERT in the first place? As I am updating the Customer entity, I would expect it to perform an UPDATE rather than an INSERT.

Comment: @aw1975 I think there could be some other operations before the call 'subscription.Customer.DaysRemaining = 20'. And that operation invokes adding a new customer to database. Try to create a small demo program to simplify the problem. Good luck.